# llevo un rato intentando averiguar que es lo que pasa en este error (Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration) es c# unity

Tags: c#, unity2d

[image: Este es el codigo]
El error es Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código _como texto, con formato_. Puedes darle formato con el botón que indica `{}` o entre tres acentos graves (```).

Comment: El error ed muy claro, tienes un problema con las llaves, solución: mirar bien tu código

Comment: Obvio que tus corchetes({ }) estan mal. segun puedo observar en la imagen, en la linea 21 ese corchete no va, borralo, agrega un corchete en la linea 41 y otro al final, en la ultima linea.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas de tus llaves están mal colocadas:

- En la línea 21 te sobra un llave de apertura `{`.
- Entre la línea 23 y la 24 te falta una llave de apertura `{`.
- Al final, debajo de la línea 47 te falta una llave de cierre `}`.